# Can i have more conditions in one while-loop?

Tags: c#, while-loop, conditional-statements

can i ask you if I can have two conditions in one while loop like this?

For example:

I've tried almost everything in my own code.

```
int a = 0;
bool b = false;

while(a!=5 || b!=true) {
a++;
}

Console.WriteLine("A is successfuly loaded into 5.");
Console.WriteLine("Bool is still " + b);
```

I expect the output to be 5, but in my program i have  an infinite loop.

Comment: Why do you expect `b!=true` to ever not be true?

Comment: Change your condition to be `(a!=5 && b!=true)` - The whole condition should evaluate as `True` in order for the loop to continue, or `False` for it to stop/exit/break

Comment: It sounds like you're interested in continuing the loop until **one** of the conditions is no longer true - if that's your intent, you should use an "and" symbol ( &&) instead of an "or" ( || )

Comment: As a matter of style, instead of writing `b!=true`, or `b==false`, it is often preferred to use `!b`. All of these are equivalent when the compile-time type of `b` is `bool`. (For a nullable Boolean `b`, they are all different.)

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop because `b` is always false, and hence, the loop continues since `||` means `OR`, and you have implemented it to continue as long as `a` is not 5 **OR** `b` is not true.

Comment: Well i thought if one statement is true in OR (beucase int is true but bool is not), the loop breaks and continue to Console line

Answer (score 0):

The variable b is set to false and does not change.

So, the condition of `b!=true` is always true.

This condition is on the right side of the "or" ( `||` ) operator.

Hence, the infinite loop results.

Answer (score 0):

This is an infinite loop because of your second condition.
`while(a!=5 || b!=true)` uses the `||` (OR) operators which means as long as one of the conditions is true, the whole condition is true

> T || F = T ---> True OR False == True
>
> F || T = T ---> False OR True == True
>
> T || T = T ---> True OR True == True
>
> F || F = F ---> False OR False == False

You assigned `b = false` and then check for `b!=true`(equivalent to `b == false` [which is what you assigned it]). This condition is `true` and because of which it infinitely enters the loop.

Both `a!=5 || b!=true` have to be false for it to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

When designing a check with multiple conditions, the key is to think about how the `&&` and `||` operations work. Using `||` will cause the loop to continue until **both** conditions are false. Using `&&` will cause the loop to continue until **either** condition is false.

In your case, you've used `||` so the loop will continue until `a=5` AND `b=true`. Since b will never be true, you've ended up with an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the exact behavior you're looking for, but there are three similar options to write your example loop, depending on how you want the two conditions to behave:

**Or**

```
while(a != 5 || b != true) {
a++;
}
```

The loop will continue if: `a != 5` evaluates "true" or `b!= true` evaluates "true" or both `a != 5` and `b!= true` evaluates "true". The first time **both** expressions evaluate to "false", the loop will exit.

**And**

```
while(a != 5 && b != true) {
a++;
}
```

The loop will continue if both `a != 5` and `b!= true` evaluates "true". The first time **one or both** of these expressions evaluates to "false", the loop will exit.

**XOR**

```
while((a != 5 && b != true) || (a == 5 && b == true  )) {
a++;
}
```

The loop will continue if both `a != 5` and `b!= true` evaluate "true", or both evaluate "false". The first time ***exactly* one** these two expressions evaluates to "false", the loop will exit.